# python pdpbox plot with unscaled feature values

Tags: python-3.x, plot

I'm trying to plot the Partial Dependence and ICE plots for a Multi-layer perceptron classifier. I'm using the UCI Adult dataset. I have Label Encoded the categorical features and Scaled the overall dataframe and then performed a test-train split on the scaled dataframe.

Now when I'm trying to plot the PDP and ICE plots I get the Age values (column in the X Axis of the plot) as scaled and hence not comprehend-able. I want the age values to be the original values before scaling was performed on the data. How can I achieve this?

This is the code for the plots:

```
from pdpbox import pdp, info_plots
pdp_age = pdp.pdp_isolate(model=mlp, dataset=X_train, model_features=X_train.columns, feature='Age')
#PDP Plot
fig, axes = pdp.pdp_plot(pdp_age, 'Age', plot_lines=False, center=False, frac_to_plot=0.5, plot_pts_dist=True,x_quantile=True, show_percentile=True)
#ICE Plot
fig, axes = pdp.pdp_plot(pdp_age, 'Age', plot_lines=True, center=False, frac_to_plot=0.5, plot_pts_dist=True,x_quantile=True, show_percentile=True)
```

[image: PDP for feature Age]

You can see from the plot that the Age values cannot be comprehended, I want the Age values to be in their true form. How can I do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the above problem by using a Pipeline object. I used one hot encoding for the categorical variables and then pushed the scaling and the classifier operations into the Pipeline object. I was then able to use the encoded X_train without any issues for the partial dependence plot and I got the actual Age value ranges, what I was looking for.

Comment: could you please give an example of how you solved it.